# Entity Framework LINQ Query match all members of child collection

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a Site table that has a many-to-many relationship with a UtilityServiceConnection table using a linking table called LinkSiteUtilityServiceConnection. Given a set of ServiceConnectionIds, I need to locate the Site that is exclusively linked to all of them and no more. I think I should be able to write the query using All on the collection but it's not working as expected.

```
var serviceConnectionIds = new[] { 546892, 546911, 546923 };

var sites1 = db.Sites
               .Where(x => x.LinkSiteUtilityServiceConnections.All(y => serviceConnectionIds.Contains(y.UtilityServiceConnectionId)))
               .ToList();
Assert.AreEqual(1, sites1.Count); //fails
```

This produces the query below that returns ~250,000 records when I expect to get one.

```
SELECT [Extent1].*
FROM   [dbo].[Site] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1]
                   FROM   [dbo].[LinkSiteUtilityServiceConnection] AS [Extent2]
                   WHERE  ([Extent1].[SiteId] = [Extent2].[SiteId])
                          AND ((NOT ([Extent2].[UtilityServiceConnectionId] IN (546892, 546911, 546923)))
                                OR (CASE
                                      WHEN ([Extent2].[UtilityServiceConnectionId] IN (546892, 546911, 546923)) THEN cast(1 as bit)
                                      WHEN (NOT ([Extent2].[UtilityServiceConnectionId] IN (546892, 546911, 546923))) THEN cast(0 as bit)
                                    END IS NULL)))
```

Why isn't All working as I expect? What's the best way to write this query?

Comment: Are you expecting to return a single value for the whole query or one for each serviceConnectionId in the array?

Comment: I'm expecting to get a single value (site) for the query. I'm trying to find the site that is linked to all three service connections and no others. So, to your point, there should be a SingleOrDefault or Select in there but I need to get closer than 250k results first. :-) I do have a workaround that gets the sites linked to any of the service connections then uses SequenceEqual to match them all. But I don't see the problem with the original query.

Comment: Why dont you use like this? db.Sites
               .Where(x => x.LinkSiteUtilityServiceConnections.All(y => serviceConnectionIds.Contains(y.UtilityServiceConnectionId))).Count();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code:

query 1:

```
var sites1 = db.Sites
    .Where(x => serviceConnectionIds.All(y =>             
                x.LinkSiteUtilityServiceConnections
                    .Select(u => u.UtilityServiceConnectionId).Contains(y)))
    .ToList();
```

query 2:

```
var query = db.Posts.AsQueryable();
var sites1 = serviceConnectionIds.Aggregate(query, 
    (current, item) => current.Where(e => e.LinkSiteUtilityServiceConnections
        .Any(c => c.UtilityServiceConnectionId== item))).ToList();
```

Comment: This appears to work. However, the profiler shows that it's generating a union of queries for each service connection id so it won't scale well. Do you have any thoughts on the problem with my original query?